# Multiply Insert to MySQL with vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i have a problem for put in multiply input

```
Try
    Dim StrSQL As String = "INSERT INTO boranga" & _
                           "(IdBorangA,Answers)" & _
                           "VALUES (@B_IdA,@B_Answer);"
    Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(StrSQL, conn.open)
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim parameterB_IdA As MySqlParameter = New MySqlParameter("@B_IdA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
    parameterB_IdA.Value = Label1.Text

    Dim parameterB_Answer As MySqlParameter = New MySqlParameter("@B_Answer", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
    parameterB_Answer.Value = TextBox1.Text

    With myCommand.Parameters
        .Add(parameterB_IdA)
        .Add(parameterB_Answer)
    End With

    Dim result As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    MsgBox("Tersimpan", vbYes, "boranga")

Catch SqlEx As MySqlException
    Throw New Exception(SqlEx.Message.ToString())
End Try
```

this current code is for putting only one input for each table "IdBorangA" and "Answer"
i try by tweak it a little bit

```
Try
    Dim StrSQL As String = "INSERT INTO boranga" & _
                           "(IdBorangA,Answers)" & _
                           "VALUES (@B_IdA,@B_Answer);"
    Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(StrSQL, conn.open)
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim parameterB_IdA As MySqlParameter = New MySqlParameter("@B_IdA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
    parameterB_IdA.Value = Label1.Text
    parameterB_IdA.Value = Label2.Text

    Dim parameterB_Answer As MySqlParameter = New MySqlParameter("@B_Answer", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
    parameterB_Answer.Value = TextBox1.Text
    parameterB_Answer.Value = TextBox2.Text

    With myCommand.Parameters
        .Add(parameterB_IdA)
        .Add(parameterB_Answer)
    End With

    Dim result As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    MsgBox("Tersimpan", vbYes, "boranga")

Catch SqlEx As MySqlException
    Throw New Exception(SqlEx.Message.ToString())
End Try
```

by adding more parameter "parameterB_IdA.Value = Label1.Text" for IdBorangA
and "parameterB_Answer.Value = TextBox2.Text" for Answer

but the result i get that the table only filling with the data from Label2.text and Textbox2.text.

i dunno what went wrong..
if you guys have any idea to help me about this problem.
feel free to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(StrSQL, conn.open)
```

the correct one is

```
Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(StrSQL, conn)
```

This query is an **INSERT** so you need to call **ExecuteNonQuery** not ExecuteReader which is intended for data retrivial with a MySqlDataReader

And, of course, you write only one record in the database not two, you are only changing the value of the parameters before sending the command to the database, only the last value will be written.